# How to rotate only iam user access key and do not rotate their secret keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk

I want to rotate AWS IAM user access keys and only access keys and not secret access keys , When I am trying to rotate keys I am able to rotate the entire keys not separately access key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to rotate only the access key ID or the secret access key, they always come together.